# Ruby OR || syntax with an object

Tags: ruby, syntax

I have seen this syntax in Ruby:

```
x = ary['value'] || Value.new
```

I get the part that if left side of the || is false, then the right side will be executed. But I do not get the part that:

```
false || (object) becomes (object)
```

I thought || should resolve to boolean. At least in most other languages. Why is Ruby resolving to an object.

Another similar question I also have:

```
'test' || true
=> "test"
```

How does 'test' get evaluated as true?

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby `nil` and `false` is evaluates to `false` only always. Look below:

```
p a = nil || 2   #=> 2
p a = false || 2 #=> 2  
p nil || false || 2 #=> 2
p '' || 2 #=> ""
```

For more reference look here [`True, False And Nil Objects In Ruby`](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/true-false-and-nil-objects-in-ruby/) and [`Ruby short circuit "or" explanation`](https://gist.github.com/mtheoryx/3138139)

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, you have four cases:

False is false

True is true

Nil is false-y

Anything else is truth-y

So,

```
5 && 8 #=> 8
5 || false #=> 5
false || 5 #=> 5
(5 && 8) == true #=> false
!!(5 && 8) == true #=> true
!!(false || nil) == false #=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

The *great rule of thumb on boolean evaluation* in Ruby is that only the objects [`NilClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/NilClass.html) and [`FalseClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/FalseClass.html) are evaluated as false. Any other object, including `String`, is evaluated to true, even if it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, as in most programming languages, some values are truthy, while others are falsey. A truthy value is `true` for the purposes of boolean evaluation, and likewise a falsey value is `false`.

However, the truthy value isn't actually cast to `true` and a falsey isn't cast to `false`, which lets the boolean expression evaluate to something useful, rather than a flat `true` or `false`.

`nil` and `false` are the only falsey values in Ruby. Note that `0` is truthy, unlike in most other languages.

See https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Any expression formed by joining together other expressions with the `||` operator will be *short-circuited*, meaning it "stops" at the first [truthy](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362) expression.

So consider this example:

```
nil || Value.new
```

The Ruby interpreter looks at `nil` first; then, since that is not truthy, it moves on to the next expression.

Now consider the example at the end of your question:

```
"test" || true
```

Ruby looks at `"test"` first; and since that is truthy, the evaluation stops there.

The same is true of the `&&` operator, which is essentially the same short-circuiting logic but only stopping once it finds a *falsey* expression.

Take this example:

```
person && person.name
```

If `person` is `nil`, then the above expression will evaluate to `nil` since that is the first falsey expression.

On the other hand:

```
person && person.male? && person.name
```

Suppose `person` is not nil, but is female. Then (presuming `male?` returned `false`) the above expression would evaluate to `false`.

And of course, if no expression is falsey, then the `&&` operator just gives you the last one (which is typically what you want).